# R - mean function warning 'argument is not numeric or logical'

Tags: r

Having a problem in R. The following works fine

```
na.omit(data)["Ozone" > 31 | "Temp" > 90]["Solar.R"]
```

and it returns

```
      Solar.R
1       190
2       118
3       149
4       313
7       299
8        99
9        19
12      256
13      290
14      274
15       65
16      334
17      307
18       78
```

However, if I pass this into a mean function

```
mean(na.omit(data)["Ozone" > 31 | "Temp" > 90]["Solar.R"])
```

the result is, well, not nice (pun!)

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(na.omit(data)["Ozone" > 31 | "Temp" > 90]["Solar.R"]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Any idea as to what is going wrong? Puns are more than welcome!

Comment: try something like `mean(unlist(...))` or directly use `colMeans` instead of `mean`

Comment: Well, it's telling you that the argument is not numeric or logical. Did you try `class(na.omit(data)["Ozone" > 31 | "Temp" > 90]["Solar.R"])`?? It's probably a factor.

Comment: @jihoward I think it is due to the fact that the object is not a vector but it's still a data frame of one column. As a matter of fact, if you do `mean(data.frame(1:10))` it returns the same error. This can be easily solved doing: `colMeans(data.frame(1:10))`

Comment: so mean(unlist(...)) works and so does colMeans, and it is a data.frame object. very strange how mean directly doesn't work, since sum, max, etc. are fine... i am also very new to R so still figuring stuff out

Comment: if you type `mean.default`, you can read that the first block of code says: `if (!is.numeric(x) && !is.complex(x) && !is.logical(x)) {warning("argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"); return(NA_real_)}`. A data frame is a `list` object, so it is not numeric, nor complex, nor logical.